# Open map in complex numbers

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Is a function $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where $f(z) = z^2$ an open map if $\mathbb{C}$ has the metric topology $d(z,a) = |z-a|$ ?

I can think of several reasons why $f$ should map open sets to open sets, but am having a difficult time generating a formal proof.

Comment: you could share your thoughts with us :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z^2 $ is holomorphic and not constant and hence open, as you are using the standard topology on $\mathbb{C}$